# Sharepoint CAML Recursive query

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I got a document library and i would like to count every file in said document library added between two chosen dates with a CAML query.

While i can find files at root, the query doesn't seem to look at documents in the folders.

Here is the query i use

```
 var query= new SPQuery
            {
                Query =
                    @"<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Content page</Value></Eq><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                    formatedStartDate +
                    "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                    formatedEndDate + "</Value></Leq></And></And></Where>",
                ViewAttributes = "scope=\"RecursiveAll\""
            };

var results = collectionList["pages"].GetItems(query).Count;
```

With more formating :

```
 <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
              <Value Type='Computed'>Content page</Value>
      </Eq>
      <And>
        <Geq>
              <FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' />
                  <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                        formatedStartDate +
                  </Value>
        </Geq>
        <Leq>
              <FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' />
                  <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                        formatedEndDate + "
                  </Value>
        </Leq>
      </And>
    </And>
  </Where>
```

Am i missing something ? Despite "RecursiveAll", there seem to be zero recursivity in this query, why ?

Comment: Try `"scope='Recursive'"`

Comment: Didn't change, only the Content Pages at root are found.

Comment: Code was fine, test conditions sucked.